# User not in AllowUsers can ssh

Tags: login, sshd, group

I have the following at the bottom of a usual `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Match Group sftpg                                                                                                                                                                                           
     ChrootDirectory /data/%u                                                                                                                                                                               
     ForceCommand internal-sftp                                                                                                                                                                             

# Personal settings                                                                                                                                                                                         
AllowUsers user1                                                                                                                                                                                           
AllowGroups user1                                                                                                                                                                                          
PermitRootLogin no
```

There are no other `AllowUsers` entries in this file and there are no other sshd configs at least under the `/etc/ssh` directory.

Despite this, `user2` can still log in via ssh. I **have fully restarted** the computer.

Shouldn't ssh be denied for every user not in `AllowUsers`? What can I try?

`id user2` returns:

```
uid=1002(user2) gid=1002(user2) groups=1002(user2),115(nopasswdlogin),999(docker)
```

Comment: Add the `id user2` output to the question ?  And confirm nothing in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d` that's conflicting/overriding the main sshd_config file ?

Comment: Do you have another line with [AllowUsers user2] ?

Comment: Is `user2` a member of group `user1`? Note the order in which sshd processes the directives: DenyUsers, AllowUsers, DenyGroups, and finally AllowGroups.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the configuration file (see `man sshd_config`) talks about `Match` blocks like this (my emphasis),

> **`Match`** Introduces a conditional block. If all of the criteria on the `Match` line are satisfied, the keywords on the following lines override those set in the global section of the config file, **until either another Match line or the end of the file.**

It also says that,

> Only a subset of keywords may be used on the lines following a `Match` keyword. Available keywords are [...] `AllowGroups`, [...] `AllowUsers`, [...] `PermitRootLogin`, [...]

So what's happening is that your `AllowGroups`, `AllowUsers`, and `PermitRootLogin` keywords are all being applied only when the `Match Group sftpg` block is in effect. It's like you've written it like this:

```
Match Group sftpg                                                                                                                                                                                           
    ChrootDirectory /data/%u                                                                                                                                                                               
    ForceCommand internal-sftp                                                                                                                                                                             
    AllowUsers user1                                                                                                                                                                                           
    AllowGroups user1                                                                                                                                                                                          
    PermitRootLogin no
```

The solution is to move your global settings above the first `Match` block so that they apply everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Move your #Personal section above Match Group/Match User section and bounce sshd. I had the same issue with AllowUsers under Match User.